# Having trouble changing classes to diferent tags of html with js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to do the same thing to body but for other tags like button, fieldset, etc

The way to change the body tag for darkmode is "document.body.classList.add("darkmode");" but i need to know the same thing but for other tags like the ones i named before.

My JS code

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

const enableDarkMode = () => {
    document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enable");
}

const disableDarkMode = () => {
    document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", null);
}

if(darkMode === "enable"){
    enableDarkMode()
}

$("#dark_mode_toggle").click(() => { 
    darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
    if (darkMode !== "enable"){
        enableDarkMode();
    }else{
        disableDarkMode();
    }
});
```

Comment: Rather than apply 'darkMode' class to a bunch of elements, just put it on `body` and then use css to inherit for all the various elements... or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I just need to change some classes to different tags of html, so for body i can simple do "document.body.classList.add("darkmode");" for selecting body tag, but doing that for other tags like button is the problem for me.

im not saying is the perfect way of doing it hahaha, but is the way i found. Adding and removing classes for the darkmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinglish's suggestion in the comments does seem right, after all CSS stands for Cascading StyleSheets, but here is a JS solution to what you were asking for.

Since it seems like you are using JQuery, you can do this:

```js
$("button").addClass("darkmode");
```

---

Without JQuery, you can do this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(element => element.classList.add("darkmode"));
```

For other elements, like fieldset, just repeat the code you chose to use from above. I think it should be trivial to figure out how to disable the dark mode using the code you already have and this.

Comment: Thanks! (to both) now i get it, im a total newbie with js so i didnt know about that use for jquery!